# Cross-platform real-time audio IO

Tags: audio, real-time, multiplatform

I am aware of two cross-platform audio libraries that cover OS X, Windows and Linux: [RTAudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio/index.html) and [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/)

I'm aware of a couple that support OS X and iOS: [Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) and [TAAE](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/)

However, I can't find anything that supports OS X, Windows and Linux and also iOS, Android

Does such a technology exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(https://www.juce.com/)(JUCE) was my choice in the end.

It is a C++ platform with a focus on real-time audio. I don't know how I missed it in the original question.

JUCE has gone from strength to strength over the past few years. Recently they have reorganised the licensing model so as to encourage independent/indie developers.

Don't want to sound too much like an advert, but I'm very happy with this technology stack.

Answer (score 1):

Un4seen's BASS audio library claims to do what you want.  I've only used it on Windows, but there is a lot of chatter about it for Android an iOS, as well as the desktop platforms.

http://www.un4seen.com/

It's free for non-commercial use, otherwise the licensing is pretty decently priced in my opinion.